# Linking Matlab and Java: Library JMatLink.dll cannot be loaded

Tags: java, matlab, dll, libraries

I want to use [JMatLink](http://jmatlink.sourceforge.net/) to connect Java with Matlab. I need to use this specific library since it is integrated in the [projeny](http://sourceforge.net/projects/projeny/) code. I have followed the steps from the documentation / other forums:

- downloaded the source code from sourceforge
- unzipped it
- copied the JMatLink.dll into C:\Windows\System32
- added the path of matlab\bin and matlab\bin\win64 to my system environment variables

However, when I try to run the class SimpleGuiTest, I get the following error message:

```
ERROR:  Could not load the JMatLink library
Win:   This error occures, if the path to
    MATLAB's <matlab>\bin directory is
    not set properly.
    Or if JMatLink.dll is not found.

Linux: Check if <matlab>/extern/lib/glnx86 (libeng.so, libmat.so, etc.)
    and <matlab>/sys/os/glnx86 (libstdc++-libc6.1-2.so.3) are in your path.

    (you can also copy missing libraries to your local path).
```

and

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: jmatlink.CoreJMatLink.setDebugNATIVE(Z)V
```

I have changed the code where the library gets loaded from

```
            System.loadLibrary("JMatLink");
```

To a command with absolute path

```
            System.load("C:\\Windows\\System32\\JMatLink.dll");
```

But I am still getting the same error message. Is it possible that the .dll is not compatible with my Win 8.1 and Matlab R2014a environment? Do I have to compile a new one for my environment? Or is there anything else that I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

I've also tried to install it without any luck a while back. I belive the reason is, as you state, that the .dll is not compatible with 64-bit operating systems/Matlab. If I remember correctly, a few of the dependencies it requires some 32-bit system libraries which was not found in my version of Windows 7 (64-bit). To map the missing dependencies I used dependencies-walker.

I had a go at compiling the source code as well, but you need to have an older version of Matlab6.5 (according to the build file) in order to compile it with the accompanying build file. More modern versions of Matlab such as [2014a](http://se.mathworks.com/support/compilers/R2014a/index.html) does not have support for the aging borland compiler used by the build file. When trying to compile the library with Borland 5.5.1, MatlabR2012b, JavaSE1.4.2 it gives me the error:

```
compile:
 [exec] Borland C++ 5.5.1 for Win32 Copyright (c) 1993, 2000 Borland
 [exec] Error E2194: Could not find file 'Files\MATLAB\R2012b\extern\include.cpp'
 [exec] Error E2194: Could not find file 'Files\MATLAB\R2012b\simulink\include.cpp'
```

It might be that you can find a way to build it with a modern supported compiler or if you get your hands on an older version of Matlab, but at this point I gave up that approached and created a wrapper using the matlabcontrol-fork [matconsolectl](https://github.com/diffplug/matconsolectl).

Hope my experience has been helpful in some way.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your experience! However, I gave up this approach after a while and worked with GenIE + jSMILE instead of Matlab + projeny.